# Is tkinter in python 3.4.4 thread safe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

The following code behaves differently in python 2.7.11 (after installing `future`) and 3.4.4

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from time import sleep

def do_something_slow():
    sleep(5)
    progressbar.grid_remove()

app = tk.Tk()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(app, mode='indeterminate')
progressbar.grid()
progressbar.start()
threading.Thread(target=do_something_slow).start()
app.mainloop()
```

In python 3.4.4 it shows a window with a progress bar that runs for 5 seconds, then **disappears**, but in python 2.7.11 it shows a window with a progress bar that runs for 5 seconds, then **the window becomes unresponsive**

I think the reason that it goes wrong when using python 2.7 is because I shouldn't be calling tkinter widgets on a different thread (tkinter is not thread safe - I should be using queues to communicate between the threads), but then why does it work in python 3.4? Is that version thread safe?

Comment: Briefly: no, it is not thread-safe.

Comment: By the way, you will have an easier time adding delays with `app.after()` rather than `threading` and `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read into `after()`, but I used a sleep in a thread for a reason; the code is greatly simplified but just enough to show the behaviour I'm seeing in my more complicated app

Comment: I expected the answer to be no, but I was hoping for an explanation as to why it works under 3.4.4

Comment: An application that is thread-safe must necessarily share threads properly, but an application that is not thread-safe will not necessarily share threads improperly.

Comment: So it's just lucky that is works in 3.4.4? OK, that's a fair explanation I suppose.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's still not thread-safe and it just happened to not break here, but I can reopen if you're wanting a more definite, detailed explanation.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting too details of an answer. It's fine to leave it closed. Thanks for your helpful comments.